# How do you create a Box<dyn Trait>, or a boxed unsized value in general?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

I have the following code

```
extern crate rand;
use rand::Rng;

pub struct Randomizer {
    rand: Box<Rng>,
}

impl Randomizer {
    fn new() -> Self {
        let mut r = Box::new(rand::thread_rng()); // works
        let mut cr = Randomizer { rand: r };
        cr
    }

    fn with_rng(rng: &Rng) -> Self {
        let mut r = Box::new(*rng); // doesn't work
        let mut cr = Randomizer { rand: r };
        cr
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

It complains that

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `rand::Rng: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:16:21
   |
16 |         let mut r = Box::new(*rng);
   |                     ^^^^^^^^ `rand::Rng` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `rand::Rng`
   = note: required by `<std::boxed::Box<T>>::new`
```

I don't understand why it requires `Sized` on `Rng` when `Box<T>` doesn't impose this on `T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

More about the `Sized` trait and bound - it's a rather special trait, which is [implicitly added](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/trait.Sized.html) to every function, which is why you don't see it listed in the prototype for [`Box::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.new):

```
fn new(x: T) -> Box<T>
```

Notice that it takes `x` by value (or move), so you need to know how big it is to even call the function.

In contrast, the `Box` type itself does *not* require `Sized`; it uses the (again special) trait bound `?Sized`, which means "opt out of the default `Sized` bound":

```
pub struct Box<T> where T: ?Sized(_);
```

If you look through, there is one way to create a `Box` with an unsized type:

```
impl<T> Box<T> where T: ?Sized
....
    unsafe fn from_raw(raw: *mut T) -> Box<T>
```

so from unsafe code, you can create one from a raw pointer.  From then on, all the normal things work.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is actually quite simple: you have a trait object, and the only two things you know about this trait object are:

- its list of available methods
- the pointer to its data

When you request to move this object to a different memory location (here on the heap), you are missing one *crucial* piece of information: **its size**.

How are you going to know how much memory should be reserved? How many bits to move?

When an object is `Sized`, this information is known at compile-time, so the compiler "injects" it for you. In the case of a trait-object, however, this information is unknown (unfortunately), and therefore this is not possible.

It would be quite useful to make this information available and to have a polymorphic move/clone available, but this does not exist yet and I do not remember any proposal for it so far and I have no idea what the cost would be (in terms of maintenance, runtime penalty, ...).

Answer (score 2):

I also want to post the answer, that one way to deal with this situation is

```
fn with_rng<TRand: Rng>(rng: &TRand) -> Self {
    let r = Box::new(*rng);
    Randomizer { rand: r }
}
```

Rust's monomorphism will create the necessary implementation of `with_rng` replacing `TRand` by a concrete sized type. In addition, you may add a trait bound requiring `TRand` to be `Sized`.